# How should I should I store my android app's images?

Tags: android

I've finished creating my first android app and I've noticed that my app's size is entirely due to it holding many, many images.  This is a Movie trivia app and each movie has an image associated with it so considering how many movies there are in the world I think I need to find a new way of storing these images.

My question is, can I store all of my images on a server somewhere(one that I own) and have the app grab the image it needs from this server?  If so, can someone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

My app is not web based so I would really like to only retrieve my images from a server while everything else(layouts,activities, etc) are stored directly on the app.

Is there a better way to deal with images that my noobish self doesn't know of?

Comment: Look into the Picasso library from Square for loading images from the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather worn out topic...

- [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)
- [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)
- [Caching Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)
- [Picasso (link to github)](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Comment: Thank you.  I knew this wasn't a unique question but the keywords I was entering into searches weren't leading me to anything.